# matplotlib.patches.Polygon function contains_point() fails to resolve a point in a patch

Tags: python, matplotlib, polygon

I am using matplotlib.patches.Polygon to update some colored patches on a graph, and I'm doing it at each iteration of the code. Since I already defined the patches in my code this way, I wanted to use
 the function contains_point() to resolve whether a point is in the
 patch or outside of it.  So Far what seems working is shapely - but I wouldn't like to do so, I'd rather keep working using matplotlib. The problem arises after calling add_patch(): in this case the patch will return the same coordinates but the function contains_point() will not return the correct value

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib import gridspec
import numpy as np
```

let's define some axes on which we want to add the patches

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,1)
axx = [plt.subplot(g) for g in gs]
```

Let's see what type is axx:

```
In[84]: axx
Out[84]: [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x7fd4b3409cd0>]
```

Let's now define a patch `b` with vertexes `v`

```
v = 
np.array([[  6.89      , -10.00907385],
           [  5.11      , -10.00907385],
           [  5.11      , -14.68307385],
           [  6.89      , -14.68307385],
           [  6.89      , -10.00907385]])  
b = [patches.Polygon(v, color = (0,0,1))]
```

we can test that:

```
In[86]: b[0].contains_point((5.5,-12))  
Out[86]: True
```

Let's now add the patch to the subplot previously initialized

```
axx[0].add_patch(b[0])
```

let's test again if the same point (5.5,-12) falls in patch `b`

```
In[88]: b[0].contains_point((5.5,-12))
Out[88]: False  
In[89]: b[0].get_xy()  
Out[89]:   
array([[  6.89      , -10.00907385],  
       [  5.11      , -10.00907385],  
       [  5.11      , -14.68307385],  
       [  6.89      , -14.68307385],  
       [  6.89      , -10.00907385]])
```

Comment: have you tried [points_inside_poly](https://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/api/nxutils_api.html)? It seems like contains_point only recognizes the path itself ([docstring](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/patches.py#L145))

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. It says `True` for me. Of course a [mcve] is needed such that any errors in the code can be excluded.

Comment: For me I get `True`, too. Which version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: >>> import matplotlib  
>>> matplotlib.__version__  
'2.1.1'

Comment: I would still suggest that you provide a [mcve], i.e. a single piece of code that one can copy and paste to test. Otherwise this is all kind of guessing here.

Comment: The problem seems a call to add_patch() of an AxesSubplot that adds the patch to the graph. If I do that before calling contains_point() it returns False. Otherwise it return True. - I will edit the question accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the polygon is added to the axes, `contains_point` uses the internal coordinates to determine whether some point is contained in the polygon.

You hence need to transform your `point` to the screen coordinate system first and then query if it is contained in the patch `poly`,

```
poly.contains_point(ax.transData.transform(point))
```

Alternatvely, use the patches' path' `contains_point` method, without specifying any transform to it,

```
poly.get_path().contains_point(point)
```

Complete example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[2,6],[4,6],[4,8],[2,8],[2,6]])  

poly = patches.Polygon(a)
point = (3,7)

cp1 = poly.contains_point(point)  
print (cp1)                                               # prints True


fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_patch(poly)

cp2 = poly.contains_point(ax.transData.transform(point))
print(cp2)                                                # prints True 
cp3 = poly.get_path().contains_point(point)
print(cp3)                                                # prints True

ax.scatter(point[0],point[1], color="crimson", zorder=6)
plt.show()
```